# Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0" framework in Azure DevOps for CD

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-devops, xamarin.android

We are facing a strange Azure DevOps pipeline build issue for our Xamarin android v10.0 update code changes.

Azure DevOps pipeline build failure error:

> ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5):
> Error : Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0"
> framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0" in the
> "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
> restore.

However we are able to build it successfully on our local devices using vs2019 and MS build.

And we checked all the possible points and found that our project is referencing “**MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0**” correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1448#issuecomment-407661649

Comment: Thanks @MohamedElrashid . But my issue is specific to Azure DevOps pipeline. As I mentioned I am able to build it locally using VS2019 and MS build.

Comment: Check machine to see if there is a folder : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5)

Comment: @jdweng yes the file is there

Comment: What version of NuGet restore are you using? Have you tried changing it?

Comment: 5.7.0   Yeah tried it didn't work.

Comment: @Pranay Deep Can you try changing the AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk to false in the project file (.csproj)? Please find more information in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/323035/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-monoandroidver-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Microsoft hosted agents? You can select the Xamarin SDK before build your app.

1 - List SDKs and included Android version adding this task to your yaml file:

```
- task: Bash@3
displayName: 'List Xamarin.Android versions'
inputs:
  targetType: 'inline'
  script: 'ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions | grep ^l'
```

[image]

2 - Select a Xamarin SDK (6_12_0 allows you to build for Android 11):

```
- script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 6_12_0 
displayName: 'Select Xamarin SDK version'
enabled: true
```

Comment: What yaml file? When creating a project with visual studio there are no yaml files anywhere...

Comment: ? Question is about azure devops pipelines not visual studio